# Codeigniter session not working with long array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I have to assign a long array to a codeigniter session but its not working. If I am using an array with three four element then this work. My array is given below.

```
     $value['id']                   = $checkout_product['checkout']['id'];
     $value['user_id']              = $checkout_product['checkout']['user_id'];
     $value['name']                 = $checkout_product['checkout']['name'];
     $value['maker']                = $checkout_product['checkout']['maker'];
     $value['model']                = $checkout_product['checkout']['model'];
     $value['color']                = $checkout_product['checkout']['color'];
     $value['size']                 = $checkout_product['checkout']['size'];
     $value['slug']                 = $checkout_product['checkout']['slug'];
     $value['route_id']             = $checkout_product['checkout']['route_id'];
     $value['description']          = $checkout_product['checkout']['description'];
     $value['quantity']             = $checkout_product['checkout']['quantity'];
     $value['p_units']              = $checkout_product['checkout']['p_units'];
     $value['images']               = $checkout_product['checkout']['images'];
     $value['label_type']           = $checkout_product['checkout']['label_type'];
     $value['product_type']         = $checkout_product['checkout']['product_type'];
     $value['auction_id']           = $checkout_product['checkout']['auction_id'];
     $value['product_id']           = $checkout_product['checkout']['product_id'];
     $value['budget_min']           = $checkout_product['checkout']['budget_min'];
     $value['budget_max']           = $checkout_product['checkout']['budget_max'];
     $value['bid_start_date']       = $checkout_product['checkout']['bid_start_date'];
     $value['bid_end_date']         = $checkout_product['checkout']['bid_end_date'];
     $value['status']               = $checkout_product['checkout']['status'];
     $value['bid_id']               = $checkout_product['checkout']['bid_id'];
     $value['bidder_id']            = $checkout_product['checkout']['bidder_id'];
     $value['bid_product_id']       = $checkout_product['checkout']['bid_product_id'];
     $value['bid_date']             = $checkout_product['checkout']['bid_date'];
     $value['bid_qty']              = $checkout_product['checkout']['bid_qty'];
     $value['bid_amount']           = $checkout_product['checkout']['bid_amount'];
     $value['total_amount']         = $checkout_product['checkout']['total_amount'];
     $value['payable_amount']       = $checkout_product['checkout']['payable_amount'];
     $value['shipping_in']          = $checkout_product['checkout']['shipping_in'];
     $value['shipping_method']      = $checkout_product['checkout']['shipping_method'];
     $value['shipping_amount']      = $checkout_product['checkout']['shipping_amount'];
     $value['pro_type']             = $checkout_product['checkout']['pro_type'];
     $value['warranty_month']       = $checkout_product['checkout']['warranty_month'];
     $value['warranty_type']        = $checkout_product['checkout']['warranty_type'];
     $value['bid_note']             = $checkout_product['checkout']['bid_note'];
     $value['bid_status']           = $checkout_product['checkout']['bid_status'];
     $value['customer_id']          = $checkout_product['checkout']['customer_id'];
     $value['customer_username']    = $checkout_product['checkout']['customer_username'];
     $value['customer_firstname']   = $checkout_product['checkout']['customer_firstname'];
     $value['customer_lastname']    = $checkout_product['checkout']['customer_lastname'];
     $value['customer_email']       = $checkout_product['checkout']['customer_email'];
     $value['customer_image']       = $checkout_product['checkout']['customer_image'];

     $this->session->set_userdata('checkout', $value);
```

This code is not working for me. Please help me how I can post big array in session in codeigniter.

Comment: I would use the database to store your sessions: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html Also, it looks like you're making a cart. Have you looked at CI's built-in cart class? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html

Answer (score 0):

By default CodeIgniter stores the session data in a cookie, which has an upper limit of `2KB-4KB` in size depending on browser.
If you are trying to store more than 4KB of data in the session you will start running into issues.

The easiest solution is to [store the session details in the DB](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). The Codeigniter session documentation details the process for storing the session in the DB.

Comment: Thanks Vinod VT for your helpful answer. Can I encrypt such kind of array. I have checked when I try to encrypt big array then this skip some data.

Comment: @hirasingh why not seralize the array?

Comment: @hirasingh there is no point in "thinking" you have access to a development environment. Try it out and see

Comment: @DarylGill I have checked before. This skipped some data. when I tried to unseralize this, only half array was printed.